# Who built the Whitewater Resort in The Cityborn?

Tags: the-cityborn

In Edward Willet's novel *The Cityborn* there is a chapter set in The Whitewater Resort. As I remember it, it is never explicitly stated who built this resort and why. It is never mentioned again after the story moves on.

So, am I missing something and it is in fact stated explicitly who built it and when? Or can we just assume it was built by/for the provosts?